# sourcing nvim config throwing error with fish shell

Tags: bash, shell, vim, fish, neovim

I recently switched to fish shell from zsh and I have been encountering errors when I update my nvim config file

It appears the error comes when checking for the `$TMUX` environmet variable in a conditional statement. I added `set shell=/bin/bash` to the config solve the problem reloading vim but the error persisted.

Here is the error from when I try `source ~/.config/nvim/init.vim`:

```
~/.config/nvim/init.vim (line 99): Illegal command name “exists("$TMUX")”
if exists("$TMUX")
   ^
from sourcing file ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
    called on line 1 of file -

in function “sv”
    called on standard input

source: Error while reading file “/home/slick/.config/nvim/init.vim”
```

Confused because I am not very solid with vimscript and am not sure which language the conditional statement in the nvim config should be written in or how to resolve this error.

Comment: Are you trying to `source ~/.config/nvim/init.vim` from your shell?

Comment: yes I am trying to source vim from my shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
source ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
```

is a Neovim command, not a shell command. There's no reason *whatsoever* to expect your shell to understand Neovim's scripting language so running that command in your shell makes no sense *at all*.

Run it in Neovim, not in your shell.

Answer (score 2):

Vim scripts that run external commands expect a POSIX compatible shell. Fish is explicitly not POSIX compatible. Add `set shell=/bin/sh` (or some other POSIX shell) to your vimrc.

Comment: I have already added this line to my config and this didn't change the output